# How to fix: Use of undeclared type 'URL' & Use of unresolved identifier 'DispatchQueue' in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsurl, nscoding

I worked on a Swift project in Xcode. I struggled to fix all errors, but I still have 2, keeping my project stuck, as you can see in the code below: **@Error1** and **@Error2**. 
I hope you could help me! Thank you in advance!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Getting the URL of the item
    for item in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
        if let item = item as? NSExtensionItem {
            for itemProvider in item.attachments! {
                //Going through each item in each input item
                if let itemProvider = itemProvider as? NSItemProvider {
                    if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeURL as String) {
                        //If the item contains a URL 
                        itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeURL as String, options: nil, completionHandler: {(content, error) -> Void in

                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                                if let url = content as? URL /*@Error1*/ {

                                    if url.absoluteString("youtube.com") || url.absoluteString.contains("youtu.be") { //@Error1.1
                                        self.setTitleOfTextView("Video")

                                        //Just in case the app isn't running in the background, write the URL to the shared NSUserDefaults
                                        var existingItems = Constants.sharedDefaults.valueForKey(Constants.videosToAdd)// sharedDefaults.value(forKey: Constants.videosToAdd) as! [String]
                                        existingItems.append(url.absoluteString) //@Errror1.2
                                        //Constants.sharedDefaults.set(existingItems, forKey: Constants.videosToAdd)
                                        //Constants.sharedDefaults.synchronize()
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(yourScore, forKey: "highScore")
                                         NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                                        //Passing URL    
                                       self.wormhole.passMessageObject(url.absoluteString as NSCoding?, identifier: "youTubeUrl")


                                    return
                                    }
                                }

                                self.setTitleOfTextView("Invalid URL.")
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **@Error1**: *'Use of undeclared type `URL`'.*
>
> Please, note that `content` from `if let url = **content** as? URL {...}`, is declared as: `let content: NSSecureCoding?`.
>
> **Update**: If I change the `URL` into `NSURL` I would get 2 more errors to:
>
> **@Error1.1** (`if url.absoluteString("youtube.com") || url.absoluteString.contains("youtu.be") {...}`): *Cannot call value of non-function type `String`*.
>
> **@Error1.2** ( `existingItems.append(url.absoluteString)`): *Value of type `AnyObject?` has no member `append`*.

```
func setTitleOfTextView(_ text: String) {
    self.mainLabel.text = text

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatch_time_t() + Double(Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) /*@Error2*/ {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { completed in
            self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: nil) { completed in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

> **@Error2**: *'Use of unresolved identifier `DispatchQueue`'*.
>
> **Update**: If I change 
>   `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatch_time_t() + Double(Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) {...}`
>   into 
>   `dispatch_after(dispatch_time_t(), Int64((3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) ) {...}`, I still get the error: *Argument type `Int64` does not conform to expected type `dispatch_queue_t` (aka `OS_dispatch_queue`)*.

Comment: Those types were introduced in Swift **3**. Which version do you use?

Comment: @MartinR I used Apple Swift version 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to struggle with this piece of code in **Swift 2.2** (using *Xcode 7*) is kinda weird... After you fixed one, another comes out. 
Switching to **Swift 3** (in *Xcode 8*) makes everything fast and clean.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the following:

1. Use NSURL instead of URL.
2. Use:

   ```
   dispatch_after(deadline:dispatch_time_t() +Int64((3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatch_time_t() + Double(Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) {`
   ```

Comment: **@Error1**: Using 'NSURL' instead of 'URL' would cause errors in 2 more places: 'if url.absoluteString("youtube.com") || url.absoluteString.contains("youtu.be") {'  and 'existingItems.append(url.absoluteString)'. **@Error2**: Changing the the syntax I guess it worked, but I still got: _Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'UInt64'_.

Comment: @RazvanJulian can you please tell me what the error in case 1 and for case 2 I have updated my answer please check

Comment: I believe the error 1.1 is due to the fact that you are calling String constructor instead of method when you write if (url.absoluteString("youtube.com")) instead it should be if (url.absoluteString.contains("youtube.com")). Now for the error 1.2 I believe you should cast the value of existingItems as [String] because as the error says there is no method named "append" on AnyObject. Please check.